# How to calculate the age of a company using the difference of between the "max" year and "min" year in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset which includes all the sales for a company in a given year (company code = gvkey, year = fyeqarq, sales = saley). I am attempting to calculate the age of a company using the last year where its sales are given and subtracting it by the first year where sales are given.

I keep running into different problems, or errors when doing so. The current one makes RStudio completely stop working. Perhaps someone could point out if there is a better way to code it? Or if it is wrong? I am fairly new to R.

I also tried using dplyrs "first" and "last", but I think I applied it the wrong way.

```
age <- function(x){
  out <- c(NA, x[seq_len(max(df_age$fyearq))]-x[seq_len(min(df_age$fyearq))])
  return(out) }

df_age$companyage <- do.call("c", by(df_age$fyearq, df_age$gvkey, age))
```

Sample from the dataset (first 100 rows) using dput:

```
structure(list(gvkey = c(1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 
1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1000L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1001L, 1003L, 
1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1003L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 
1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1004L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 1005L, 
1006L, 1006L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1007L, 1008L, 1008L, 
1008L, 1008L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 
1009L, 1009L, 1009L, 1009L), fyearq = c(1969L, 1970L, 1971L, 
1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 1983L, 1984L, 
1985L, 1986L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
1990L, 1968L, 1969L, 1970L, 1971L, 1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 
1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 
1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 
1994L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 1978L, 1979L, 
1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1982L, 1983L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 
1986L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 
1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L), saley = c(7.095, 
9.478, 7.983, 8.201, 8.467, 9.961, 11.295, 16.226, 18.014, 18.92, 
4.921, 6.434, 7.865, 13.997, 2.647, 2.419, 2.761, 7.392, 8.852, 
79.894, 48.393, 19.502, 1.694, 4.166, 5.063, 5.185, 7.555, 11.174, 
13, 13.979, 18.381, 20.496, 28.669, 32.563, 30.454, 41.766, 40.465, 
40.475, 52.723, 53.836, 66.376, 74.543, 90.007, 108.635, 116.092, 
107.339, 98.072, 98.306, 97.191, 1212.356, 1422.924, 1863.645, 
2582.936, 2596.419, 2222.306, 1680.935, 1522.926, 1572.618, 1789.764, 
2133.438, 2541.417, 3300.719, 3549.624, 3260.308, 4386.042, 5029.107, 
5364.4, 4400.8, 3966.3, 4134.1, 3869, 4239.5, 1425.9, 1.293, 
2.583, 3.762, 6.872, 7.231, 2.287, 2.289, 1.724, 1.334, 1.009, 
1.064, 1.204, 0.065, 0.469, 0.08, 1.022, 3.565, 4.436, 4.939, 
5.013, 4.508, 4.581, 8.058, 8.16, 8.373, 9.362, 169.922)), row.names = c(6735L, 
8891L, 11367L, 14026L, 16823L, 19660L, 22506L, 25386L, 28253L, 
31209L, 50854L, 57451L, 64185L, 71149L, 50855L, 57452L, 64186L, 
71150L, 78490L, 85850L, 93149L, 100335L, 4810L, 6736L, 8892L, 
11368L, 14027L, 16824L, 19661L, 22507L, 25387L, 28254L, 31210L, 
34111L, 36988L, 39814L, 44656L, 50856L, 57453L, 64187L, 71151L, 
78491L, 85851L, 93150L, 100336L, 107454L, 114551L, 121923L, 129787L, 
138848L, 149183L, 159747L, 170254L, 181110L, 191976L, 202480L, 
212402L, 221703L, 230643L, 239235L, 247644L, 255712L, 263449L, 
270929L, 278189L, 285331L, 292379L, 299553L, 306708L, 313762L, 
320630L, 327242L, 333472L, 31211L, 34112L, 36989L, 39815L, 44657L, 
44658L, 50857L, 44659L, 50858L, 57454L, 64188L, 71152L, 50859L, 
57455L, 64189L, 71153L, 50860L, 57456L, 64190L, 71154L, 78492L, 
85852L, 93151L, 100337L, 107455L, 114552L, 121924L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also would have gone for a dplyr approach, so a comment on what might have wrong when you tried it.

The problem with `first` and `last` is that they take the first and last values in an array, **independently of their values**. So, for example

```
example <- c(10, 0, 999, -1)
> first(example)
[1] 10
> last(example)
[1] -1
```

For your problem, what you really want is the `min` and `max` values of the array:

```
> min(example)
[1] -1
> max(example)
[1] 999
```

No, going to your case of interest (I called the data you gave `df`):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(gvkey) %>% 
  summarize(age = max(fyearq) - min(fyearq))

# A tibble: 9 x 2
  gvkey   age
  <int> <dbl>
1  1000     9
2  1001     3
3  1003     7
4  1004    50
5  1005     4
6  1006     1
7  1007     4
8  1008     3
9  1009    10
```

What we did there was first group by each company's id, so the min and max values would be calculated within each company. Then we summarized, subtracting the min year from the max year.

Alternatively, you can use `mutate` to add the ages to the data frame as a new column:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(gvkey) %>% 
  mutate(age = max(fyearq) - min(fyearq)) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 100 x 4
   gvkey fyearq saley   age
   <int>  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1000   1969  7.10     9
 2  1000   1970  9.48     9
 3  1000   1971  7.98     9
 4  1000   1972  8.20     9
 5  1000   1973  8.47     9
 6  1000   1974  9.96     9
 7  1000   1975 11.3      9
 8  1000   1976 16.2      9
 9  1000   1977 18.0      9
10  1000   1978 18.9      9
# ... with 90 more rows
```

**Edit**: For a short intro to dplyr's logic and some of it's most useful functions, [this chapter of R for Data Science](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html) is really good, and it's contents go a long way.

Answer (score 2):

You might use `tapply` to calculate the `diff`erence of the `range` of variable `fyearq` for each company

```
tapply(df_age$fyearq, df_age$gvkey, function(x) diff(range(x)))
#1000 1001 1003 1004 1005 1006 1007 1008 1009 
#   9    3    7   50    4    1    4    3   10
```

Or try `aggregate`

```
aggregate(fyearq ~ gvkey, df_age, FUN = function(x) diff(range(x)))
#  gvkey fyearq
#1  1000      9
#2  1001      3
#3  1003      7
#4  1004     50
#5  1005      4
#6  1006      1
#7  1007      4
#8  1008      3
#9  1009     10
```